# How to demostrate that $\int_{\{a\}} f(x) d \mu= \mu(\{a\}) f(a)$?

Tags: calculus, measure-theory

I don´t know how to demostrate that:

$$\int_{\{a\}} f(x) d \mu= \mu(\{a\}) f(a)$$

Note: I have read  on a book that "The Lebesgue Integral of a constant function on a measurable set will be that constant times the Lebesgue measure of the set" but I don´t know how  to demostrate it.

Comment: This follows directly from the definition of the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Is your function constant at $a$, or are your evaluating at $a$? In the latter case, isn't the measure of $a$ zero? And is $\mu$ Lebesque measure? This question may be trivial with more information.

Comment: The function is not constant, I am evaluating at a. And $\mu$ is not the lebeasgue measure.

Comment: $\mu$ is defined as a measure supported in $a$.

Comment: OK, see my answer, which assumed your responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write
$$\int_{\{a\}} f\mathsf d\mu = \int f\chi_{\{a\}}\mathsf d\mu. $$
Since $$f\chi_{\{a\}}(x) = \begin{cases} f(a),& x=a\\ 0,& x\ne a\end{cases},$$
we have
$$ \int f\chi_{\{a\}}\mathsf d\mu = \int f(a)\chi_{\{a\}}\mathsf d\mu = f(a)\int \chi_{\{a\}}\mathsf d\mu = f(a)\mu(\{a\}). $$

Comment: If you understand the indicator function $\chi$, then this is a very nice answer.

Comment: I understand the first part of the demostration: $\int_{\{a\}} f(x)\mathsf d\mu(x) = \int f(x)\chi_{\{a\}}\mathsf(x) d\mu(x)=\int f(a)\chi_{\{a\}}\mathsf d\mu(x) $. However I don´t understan the last equality :(

Comment: When you put $f$ you mean $f(x)$, do you?

Comment: The last equality is by definition? Thank yoy very much :)

Comment: $f$ is a function. $f(x)$ is the value of $f$ at $x$. For example, we could define the map $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by $x\mapsto 2x$. Then for any $x\in\mathbb R$, $f(x)=2x$. But in this case, $f(x)$ is a real number, while $f$ is a function - two different things.

The last equality, yes. What is the integral of a characteristic function with respect to a positive measure?

Comment: @trb456 Understanding the indicator/characteristic function $\chi$ is essential to the definition of the Lebesgue integral...

Comment: I understand what you have told about f. So it would be more correct to put  $\int_{\{a\}} f(x)\mathsf d\mu(x)$ than $\int_{\{a\}} f\mathsf d\mu$, wouldn´t be? Or $\int_{\{a\}} f(x)\mathsf \mu(dx)$?

Comment: But if $\mu$ is not the Lebesgue measure, the integral shoudn´t be the Lebesgue integral, should be?

Comment: @Edin_91 By "Lebesgue integral" I mean the integral of a real-valued function with respect to a measure (not necessarily Lebesgue measure).

As for your second question, it is just notation. If the function $f$ is understood then there is no need to write a dummy variable (e.g. $x$). For $\mathsf d\mu(x)$ vs. $\mu(\mathsf dx)$, that is just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only evaluating $f$ at a single point $a$, then we can consider the restriction of $f$ at $a$ to be a *simple function* (a function with a finite number of values), and then the right-hand side of your equation is the *definition* of the left-hand side of your equation. This is true regardless of your measure $\mu$. That is, the integral of a simple function on some set is *defined* to be the sum of the products equal to the values of the function times the measure of the subset that takes that function value. In your case, there is only one value $f(a)$ and thus only one set {$a$} whose measure we need $\mu(\{a\})$.

Comment: I do not completely understand it. Could ypu explain more detailed please?

Comment: How is this this edit? Do you know what a simple function is? In Papa Rudin, for example, this is the standard abstract way to construct the integral, starting with simple functions.

Comment: You might want to write $\mu(\{a\})$ to use proper notation, especially when dealing with intro-level questions about measure theory.

Comment: @AlexR: Agreed!